# Spring Jasper Integration with Parent and Sub Report using Model beside of SQL Query

Tags: spring, jasper-reports, sql

I have two domain code:

```
public class domain1{

private string domain1Name;
private List<domain2> domain2List;

/* getter setter */
}

public class domain2{

private string domain2Name;

/* getter setter */
}
```

and i have a Spring Controller returning a map then pass it to the model with the following function:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping("preview")
    public String preview(Model model) { 
            List<Domain1> list = new ArrayList<Domain1>();
            Domain1 d1 = new Domain1();
            Iterator i = someData.iterator(); //<--this function successfully retrieve data, not null guaranted.
        while(i.hasNext()){
              Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
              d1 = (Domain1) me.getValue();
              list.add(d1);
        }

        Map mapz = new HashMap();
        mapz.put("domain1List", list); // first value as Domain1
        mapz.put("domain2List", d1.getDomain2List()); // second value as Domain2
        model.addAllAttributes(mapz);

        return "test_parentreport"; <- jasper bean lookup views from views.xml
    }
```

views.xml

```
<bean id="test_parentreport"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView"
    p:url="/WEB-INF/jasper/test_parentreport.jrxml">
    <property name="headers">
        <props>
            <prop key="Content-Disposition">
                attachment; filename=test_parentreport.pdf
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="subReportUrls">
        <map>
            <entry key="test_subreport" value="/WEB-INF/jasper/test_subreport.jrxml"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

test_parentreport.jrxml

```
...<field name="domain1Name" class="java.lang.String"/><detail><band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="51"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{domain1Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="125" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
            <subreportExpression class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"><![CDATA[$P{test_subreport}]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</detail>...
```

test_subreport.jrxml

```
...<field name="domain2Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
<detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="71" y="13" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{domain2Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<noData>
    <band height="50">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[NODATA ]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</noData>...
```

my problem are:

imagine Domain1.class contains only one element, it brings List which contain 2 elements,

-Domain1 <-- i want to fill this on test_parentreport.jrxml as parent report
--Domain2
--Domain2 <-- i want to fill these two on test_subreport.jrxml

when i put only 1 map on controller, the report worksfine on parent, but return NO DATA on subreport
when i put two map on controller, the report show blank both parent and sub report

am i missing something ? please kindly give me a clue
the idea is fill both parent and subreport using Domain / Model beside SQL Query, i try this on SQL Query both parent and subreport works fine, but its broken when i change it into a Model.

Answer (score 1):

You might find some clues by checking my tutorials for Spring 3 MVC and Jasper:

I've provided a downloadable Maven build. The tutorials are very detailed. In addition, the application itself is well-commented. Just leave a comment if the tutorials help you :)

http://krams915.blogspot.com/p/tutorials.html